# IllegalArgumentException when validating a date on DatePickerDialog (Android)

Tags: android, datepicker, illegalargumentexception, datepickerdialog

I'm having an IllegalArgumentException when I validate a date on a DatePickerDialog. Here is the stacktrace:

```
10-27 19:50:34.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1188): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-27 19:50:34.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1188): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
10-27 19:50:34.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at java.text.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:365)
10-27 19:50:34.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at java.text.Format.format(Format.java:93)
10-27 19:50:34.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at com.boka.lesbonscomptes.ActivityMain$1.onDateSet(ActivityMain.java:43)
10-27 19:50:34.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at android.app.DatePickerDialog.onClick(DatePickerDialog.java:111)
10-27 19:50:34.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
10-27 19:50:34.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-27 19:50:34.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-27 19:50:34.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
10-27 19:50:34.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-27 19:50:34.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-27 19:50:34.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
10-27 19:50:34.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
10-27 19:50:34.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and my code

```
    public class ActivityMain extends Activity {

    //Attributs UI
    private LinearLayout layoutNouvelleDepense = null;
    private Button bDate = null;

    private GregorianCalendar gcDate = null;

    //util
    private SimpleDateFormat sdfAjd = null;
    static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 1;


    /*LISTENER*/

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "ok",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //La date est calée sur le choix de l'utilisateur
            gcDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
            //Le bouton est mis à jour avec la date choisie
            bDate.setText(sdfAjd.format(gcDate));
        }
    };  

    private OnClickListener oclBoutonDate = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);     
        }
    };      


    /*METHODES*/
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        layoutNouvelleDepense = (LinearLayout) LinearLayout.inflate(this,R.layout.nouvelle_depense, null);
        bDate = (Button) layoutNouvelleDepense.findViewById(R.id.bDate);

        bDate.setOnClickListener(oclBoutonDate);

        gcDate = new GregorianCalendar();
        sdfAjd = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.getDefault());

        bDate.setText(sdfAjd.format(gcDate.getTime()));

        setContentView(layoutNouvelleDepense);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    @Override    
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) 
    {
        System.out.println("DATE = " + gcDate.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR) + "/" + gcDate.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) + "/" +  gcDate.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
         return new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener, gcDate.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR), gcDate.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH), gcDate.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    }
}
```

I have no issues in creating the dialog, and the date is correctly initialized when the dialog is displayed.

No matter the date chosen, the IllegalArgumentException is raised.

I've been looking for an answer since quite a while, but all the similar posts are about excepetion raised at the creation of the dialog, not the validation of the date.

Can you please help me find out what's going on ?

Thank you

Comment: This line cause the exception `sdfAjd.format(gcDate)`. You are passing invalid argument to `format()` method of **SimpleDateFormat** class. Also I have doubt of Initialization of `sdfAjd` Object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your OnDateSetListener add `getTime()` to your format command:

```
bDate.setText(sdfAjd.format(gcDate.getTime()));
```

The difference is that `GregorianCalendar#getTime()` returns a Date object and calls `SimpleDateFormat#format(Date)` which, as you know, works fine in your `onCreate()` method.

But `format(gcDate)` by itself calls the generic `SimpleDateFormat#format(Object)` method which throws the exception because this `format()` does not understand the Date object.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I didn't noticed I missed this, and I never thought it'd be because of this, since in debug I didn't even enter the "onDateSet" defined in my source after validating the dialog. thanks :)

Comment: No trouble. Understand that your LogCat shows that `onDateSet()` is called: `at com.boka.lesbonscomptes.ActivityMain$1.onDateSet(ActivityMain.java:43)` so be careful how you are using the debugger! Good luck!